# Google Calendar Feed Rendering 1 entry into 2

Tags: rss, feed, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Here is my podcast's feed:
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/eci0cg9lo08bfp5uuuci7rk33k%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?futureevents=true&orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending

As you can see, Episode 85 is being listed twice, but both links point to the 1 Episode 85 entry in the calendar.

Further down the feed, it happens again for Episode 92 -- lists it as 2 separate entries, when clicking on either link takes you to Episode 92.

Google Calendar feed bug? Why? Any other way to render this list without these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it looks like there's an issue with using recurring events and Google Calendar. By removing recurring events, the entries show up as expected in the feed.